# Negate a Statement in Contrapositive Form

Tags: logic, soft-question, predicate-logic

Consider the following statement:

> If $f_1(x_1^*) = f_n(x_n^*)$ for all $n \geq 1$, then $x_1^* = x_n^* = 1$ for all $n \geq 1$.

I would like to write down the contrapositive statement. Here is my thinking:

> Suppose that there exists an $n \geq 1$ such that $x_n^* \neq 1$, then $f_1(x_1^*) \neq f_n(x_n^*)$.

My question is the following: Do I really need to include the quantifier for the statement after "then"? ;i.e., do I have to say
$f_1(x_1^*) \neq f_n(x_n^*)$ for **some** $n$ ? If so, then I think I have "two $n$" flows around which confuses me a lot. Or can I just recycle the $n$ used in the sentence of "suppose..." Is this the correct way to think of?

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: The "contrapositive" of a statement has nothing to do with the "negation" of a statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If $f_1(x_1^*) = f_n(x_n^*)$ for all $n \geq 1$, then $x_1^* = x_n^* = 1$ for all $n \geq 1$.

It's clear here that the two $n$'s refer to different $n$, as for both statements it's explained that they hold for *any* $n$. Nevertheless, you repeated the quantifier, *as you should*.

When you make the contrapositive, you should *especially* also repeat the quantifier to make sure the reader understands we're talking about different $n$, especially because in this case we're considering *specific values of $n$*:

> Suppose that there exists an $n \geq 1$ such that $x_n^* \neq 1  \color{red}{\vee x^*_1\neq 1}$, then there exists an $n \geq 1$ such that $f_1(x_1^*) \neq f_n(x_n^*)$.

Even better would be to use a different variable to completely remove ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot recycle the $n$. Try replacing the $n$ in the first statement with $m$, and it still retains the same meaning. In other words, they are two separate variables in two separate scopes, but with the same name. That's bad practice, precisely because of the confusion you have now.

Comment: I realized I misread the first part the moment I posted this, my answer is now a complete negation of my previous one. Thank you, @orlp.

Answer (score 1):

Your original statement is $p \to q$. You want $\neg q \to \neg p$.

Not knowing anything else about your statements, I'd think $\neg q$ is

"$x_1^* \neq  1$ or $x_n^* \neq 1$ for some $n \geq 1$",

And $\neg p$ would be

"$f_1(x_1^*) \neq f_n(x_n^*)$ for some $n \geq 1$".

Comment: The $x^*_1 \neq x^*_n$ is superfluous.

Comment: @orlp I was wondering about that, but aren't there three equalities in that statement? Both $x$'s equal $1$, and they equal each other?

Comment: When $x^*_1 \neq 1 \vee x^*_n \neq 1$ does __not__ hold, we already know that $x^*_1 \neq x^*_n$ won't hold either, because they're both equal to $1$.

Comment: @orlp Thanks, you're right.